# MPandroid chart Xline why see a value between data

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

```
ScatterChart scatterChart = (ScatterChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);      

ScatterDataSet dataset = new ScatterDataSet(entries, "온도");

//ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

ScatterData data = new ScatterData(labels, dataset);
scatterChart.setData(data);


scatterChart.setDescription("Description");        
dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS); //
dataset.setScatterShapeSize(8);
dataset.setScatterShape(ScatterChart.ScatterShape.CIRCLE);
scatterChart.animateY(2000);      

scatterChart.setScaleXEnabled(false);
scatterChart.setScaleYEnabled(false);
scatterChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Please refer to the picture.

[image]

Comment: Why is your question not clear? Which line ? What error? What issue? Please explain.

Comment: Where is labels defined?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that there is an additional value between your data that is causing your chart to be drawn that way, instead not all labels are drawn on your x-axis due to limited space. If you really want to show all labels you could try the following:

```
XAxis xAxis = scatterChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(0);
xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(0);
```